# Adding a Disable Button to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to add a disable button in the popup window of my chrome extension that will have it pause functionality like the Adblock extension does. This would remain paused in all tabs until the button is clicked to re-enable it. I have the following code in place, however, the button and functionality don't currently work.

Popup.js file:

```
function disableButton() {
    var disableButton = document.getElementById("disableButton");
    var isExtensionOn = true;
    if (disableButton.innerHTML == "Disable") {
        isExtensionOn = false;
    } else if (disableButton.innerHTML == "Enable") {
        isExtensionOn = true;
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var singleButton = document.getElementById("singleButton");
    var br1 = document.getElementById("br1");
    var br2 = document.getElementById("br2");
    //Sends message to event.js (background script) telling it to disable the
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "setOnOffState", data: {value: isExtensionOn} });

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "getOnOffState"}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response == true){
            disableButton.innerHTML = "Disable";
            disableButton.className = "button button3"
            disableButton.style.display = "";
            br1.style.display = "";
            br2.style.display = "";
        }
        if (response == false){
            disableButton.innerHTML = "Enable";
            disableButton.className = "button button1"
            disableButton.style.display = "";
            br1.style.display = "";
            br2.style.display = "";
        }
    });
```

There is more code below this, but it is functioning code that cannot be shared out.

Popup.html:

```
<button class="button button1" id="disableButton" style="display:none">Error</button>
    <br id="br1" style="display:none">
<br id="br2" style="display:none">
```

Background.js:

```
var isExtensionOn = true;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.cmd == "setOnOffState") {
        isExtensionOn = request.data.value;
    }

    if (request.cmd == "getOnOffState") {
        sendResponse(isExtensionOn);
    }
});
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After going through the code that you have provided, it seems like there are some trivial misses that happened in the code, which led to the functionality failure.

I'll be pointing out the mistakes you have done here :

- In *Popup.js*, the variable **isExtensionOn** has the **functional scope** of the `disableButton()`, and hence **cannot** be accessed inside the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { })` event listener.

  > The value of **isExtensionOn** inside this listener function would be `undefined`, which is not something that you expect in your system.

  To fix this, you just need to define the variable isExtensionOn on a level above (say global level), so that it is accessible to both `function disableButton() { })` and the event listener of `DOMContentLoaded`.
- In *Popup.js*, the function block `chrome.extension.sendMessage({cmd: "getOnOffState"}, function (response) { })` contains a **disableButton**,
  which I see is nowhere defined within the functional scope of the event listener of `DOMContentLoaded`. And you are performing assignment to it, which would throw you **errors** in the console of whatever browser you are using which would look like:

  > `Uncaught ReferenceError: disableButton is not defined`

  To fix this issue, you need to define the **disableButton** within the scope of the event listener of `DOMContentLoaded`.
- In *Popup.js*, inside the event listener of `DOMContentLoaded`, you have defined a variable **singleButton** as `var singleButton = document.getElementById("singleButton");`, but I see that in the *Popup.html* file that you have provided, there is no element but the `id` of **singleButton**.

  > This would return you a value of `null`, again which is something that you are not looking forward to have in your system.

  To fix this issue, you need to correct the `id` mentioned, as `document.getElementById("disableButton");` within the scope of the event listener of `DOMContentLoaded`.

> **NOTE** : I am mentioning some conventions that you can follow for better coding practises
>
> > 1. Naming for all the *html files* need to start with **lower cases**.
> > 2. Use `===` instead of `==` for strict comparision. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/6384636) for more details about the same.
> > 3. Use proper indentations so as to not miss out any *braces* or commit unintentional errors. (You had missed out a `})` in the code block where you defined the event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`)

Hence to sum up, I am writing the entire code of all the files that you have mentioned here with the **appropriate corrections**:

*popup.html* :

```
<button class="button button1" id="disableButton" style="display:none">Error</button>
<br id="br1" style="display:none">
<br id="br2" style="display:none">
```

*Popup.js* :

```
var isExtensionOn = true;

function disableButton() {
    var disableButton = document.getElementById("disableButton");
    if (disableButton.innerHTML === "Disable") {
        isExtensionOn = false;
    } else if (disableButton.innerHTML === "Enable") {
        isExtensionOn = true;
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var disableButton = document.getElementById("disableButton");
    var br1 = document.getElementById("br1");
    var br2 = document.getElementById("br2");

//Send message to event.js (background script) telling it to disable the extension.

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({cmd: "setOnOffState", data: {value: isExtensionOn}});

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({cmd: "getOnOffState"}, function (response) {
        if (response !== undefined) {
            if (response) {
                disableButton.innerHTML = "Disable";
                disableButton.className = "button button3";
                disableButton.style.display = "";
                br1.style.display = "";
                br2.style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                disableButton.innerHTML = "Enable";
                disableButton.className = "button button1";
                disableButton.style.display = "";
                br1.style.display = "";
                br2.style.display = "";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

*Background.js* :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.cmd === "setOnOffState") {
            isExtensionOn = request.data.value;
        }

        if (request.cmd === "getOnOffState") {
            sendResponse(isExtensionOn);
        }
    });
```

This should work as per your requirement. Please go through the answer and let me know if you face any more issues in this regard.

Answer (score 8):

The part of the script you provide has a scoping error.
See this line in the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "setOnOffState", data: {value: isExtensionOn} });
```

As far as I can tell, there is no variable named `isExtensionOn` in that scope. It is defined in the function scope of `disableButton ()`, but not in the event. Therefore, your script will tell the backend to set the variable to `undefined`.

When you then proceed to check the value against `true` and `false`, neither of that will be the value. That could cause the problem. To fix it, change `{value: isExtensionOn}` to `{value: false}`.

Second, you are using a button with the id `singleButton`, even though there is not a button with this id. You are assigning it to variable `singleButton`, but further down below, you are using a button called `disableButton`, which is not defined.

Also, your last line is missing closing parenthesis: `})`. After fixing all these issues, the plugin works just fine, I've tested it.

**Tip:**

You can debug your extension and view errors by opening the popup, right-clicking on it and then choosing `Inspect Element`. Switch to the console tab. It will have the JavaScript errors in it.

Answer (score 3):

The popup window can access the background script directly, through `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`, therefore making it way simpler:

**popup.js**

```
var backgroundPage;
var theButton = document.querySelector("button");

function updateButton(onOrOff){
    theButton.innerHTML = onOrOff ? "Disable" : "Enable";
    theButton.className = onOrOff ? "button button3" : "button button1";
}        

function toggleButton(){
    backgroundPage.isExtensionOn = !backgroundPage.isExtensionOn;
    updateButton(backgroundPage.isExtensionOn);
}

chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
    backgroundPage = bgPage;
    updateButton(bgPage.isExtensionOn);
    theButton.onclick = toggleButton;
    theButton.style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("br1").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("br1").style.display = "";
});

//the rest of your code just needs to check backgroundPage.isExtensionOn
//to see if the extension is on or not.
```

**popup.html**

```
<button class="button button1" id="disableButton" style="display:none">Error</button>
<br id="br1" style="display:none">
<br id="br2" style="display:none">
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**background.js**

```
var isExtensionOn = true;  //this will be changed by popup.js directly.
```